# Hyperledger Fabric: DiscoveryService: framework error: failed constructing descriptor for chaincode: <chaincode name>

Tags: node.js, docker, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I know this may have been asked before but I will post this once again to bring it back to the surface.

I have created a hyperledger fabric network with one organization with two peers.
Each peer is set up in a different server and they can communicate. I used domain names and started the peers as docker containers.

This is my docker compose file from the peer 1:

```
peer1.org:
    restart: always
    container_name: peer1.org
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$IMAGE_VERSION
    environment:
      #Generic peer variables
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=net_hypercube
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      # Peer specific variabes
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org:5055
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:5055
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer1.org:5056
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:5056
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=bc.domain.com:5051
      # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ENDPOINT=0.0.0.0:5051
      # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org:5051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=ORGMSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org/peers/peer1.org/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org/peers/peer1.org/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer1.org:/var/hyperledger/production
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 5055:5055
    networks:
      - orgnetwork
```

The docker compose file of the second peer is identical and runs in the other server.

In the server 1 we have:
Peer 1
Orderer
Ca of Orderer
In the server 2 we have:
Peer 2
Ca of Org

In server 1 I have created a channel and joined peer 1. I have downloaded and uploaded the genesis file in the other server and when the peer 2 is up I joined this peer as well using the genesis file.

From all the logs I am able to see that hte peers communicate with gossip normally and everyone sees each other.

Next, I have installed in both peers the chaincode (name = framework) (golang), I approved and committed the chaincode using peer 1 for the single org that exists.
If I invoke it from peer 1  it writes perfectly well using the cli and I can see data in both peers as it is trasmitted using gossip to the peer2. So everything normal so far.

Now the good part. I am using of course a gateway app which is in node js and uses the sdk. I have created the connection yaml file that includes the info only of the peer 1 as the endorser.

When I invoke it with the app I get the error message: DiscoveryService: framework error: failed constructing descriptor for chaincode: <name:”framework”>

These are the logs in the peer 1:
[image]

This is the error message:
[image]

Tested:
If gateway connects to channel (success)
If tls certs for Orderer and peer are correct (success)
Chaincode is installed in both peers (success)
Chaincode in channel isntalled (success)

I am not sure what else I need to test and how can I solve this issue. It is very weird for me to see that from the peer on the cli in the server everything works fine but with the sdk I get errors regarding the chaincode name.

```
---
#
# The network connection profile provides client applications the information about the target
# blockchain network that are necessary for the applications to interact with it. These are all
# knowledge that must be acquired from out-of-band sources. This file provides such a source.
#
name: "network"

#
# Any properties with an "x-" prefix will be treated as application-specific, exactly like how naming
# in HTTP headers or swagger properties work. The SDK will simply ignore these fields and leave
# them for the applications to process. This is a mechanism for different components of an application
# to exchange information that are not part of the standard schema described below. In particular,
# the "x-type" property with the "hlfv1" value example below is used by Hyperledger Composer to
# determine the type of Fabric networks (v0.6 vs. v1.0) it needs to work with.
#
x-type: "hlfv1"

#
# Describe what the target network is/does.
#
description: "A gateway connection file for the hypercube network"

#
# Schema version of the content. Used by the SDK to apply the corresponding parsing rules.
#
version: "1.1"

#
# [Optional]. But most apps would have this section so that channel objects can be constructed
# based on the content below. If an app is creating channels, then it likely will not need this
# section.
#
channels:
  # name of the channel
  channel:
    # Required. list of orderers designated by the application to use for transactions on this
    # channel. This list can be a result of access control ("org1" can only access "ordererA"), or
    # operational decisions to share loads from applications among the orderers.  The values must
    # be "names" of orgs defined under "organizations/peers"
    orderers:
      - orderer.author

    # Required. list of peers from participating orgs
    peers:
      peer1.org:
        # [Optional]. will this peer be sent transaction proposals for endorsement? The peer must
        # have the chaincode installed. The app can also use this property to decide which peers
        # to send the chaincode install request. Default: true
        endorsingPeer: true

        # [Optional]. will this peer be sent query proposals? The peer must have the chaincode
        # installed. The app can also use this property to decide which peers to send the
        # chaincode install request. Default: true
        chaincodeQuery: true

        # [Optional]. will this peer be sent query proposals that do not require chaincodes, like
        # queryBlock(), queryTransaction(), etc. Default: true
        ledgerQuery: true

        # [Optional]. will this peer be the target of the SDK's listener registration? All peers can
        # produce events but the app typically only needs to connect to one to listen to events.
        # Default: true
        eventSource: true

    chaincodes:
      # the format follows the "cannonical name" of chaincodes by fabric code
      - frameworksc:1.0
      - framework:1.0
      
# list of participating organizations in this network
#
organizations:
  ORG:
    mspid: ORGMSP
    peers:
      - peer1.org

#
# List of orderers to send transaction and channel create/update requests to. For the time
# being only one orderer is needed. If more than one is defined, which one get used by the
# SDK is implementation specific. Consult each SDK's documentation for its handling of orderers.
#
orderers:
  orderer.author:
    url: grpcs://orderer.author:7055

    # these are standard properties defined by the gRPC library
    # they will be passed in as-is to gRPC client constructor
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: domainName.com
    tlsCACerts:
      path:  ./network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/author/orderers/orderer.author/tls/tlscacerts/tls-bc-seif-io-7004-ca_authorizer.pem
       
#
# List of peers to send various requests to, including endorsement, query
# and event listener registration.
#
peers:
  peer1.org:
    # this URL is used to send endorsement and query requests
    url: grpcs://peer1.org:5055
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: domainName.com
    tlsCACerts:
      path: ./network/organizations/peerOrganizations/hypercube/peers/peer1.hypercube/tls/tlscacerts/tls054-ca_.pem

certificateAuthorities:
  #
  # [Required]. MagnetoCorp CA
  #
```

Above is the connection yaml file I am using in the node js.
To be noted that I am able to register successfully new users in the certificate authority using the node js application and the gateway. (certificateAuthorities not included in the post)

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Please share logs and error message in the plain text format